# JPA 2 Mapping inheritance Type JOINED or SINGLE?

Tags: inheritance, annotations, jpa-2.0, discriminator

I've a test case, that have three tables/classes (Language, Caption and CaptionLanguage).

The Language table stores the languages data.
The Caption table stores the caption index data.
The CaptionLanguage table stores the caption data per language.

[image: MER]

Which Inheritance type I can use to solve the problem?

If I set the "@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ID_LANG",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.Integer)",
with the "@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)", will work?
Without use the @DiscriminatorValue(value="Value")

Thanks!

Comment: What entities have you defined, are you trying to define? What relationships are defined between them? I don't think I can answer you too well because I don't think I see any inheritance "is-a" relationships in your model, but rather "has-a" aggregation type of relationship. Perhaps you could clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like issue that could be solved by inheritance. Despite name, `CaptionLanguage` is not subtype of `Language` - it is also not subtype of `Caption`.

Instead it looks like three entities with following characteristic:

- one-to-many from `Language` to `CaptionLanguage` (and/or many-to-one inverse)
- one-to-many from `Caption` to `CaptionLanguage` (and/or possibly many-to-one inverse)
- many-to-one from `Caption` to parent `Caption` (and/or one-to-many inverse)
- `CaptionLanguage` does have composite primary key, so [@IdClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html), [or @EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html)  should be used.